# How looks a string array with a string index in a method signature?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following method:

```
public test(keyValue : { [index:string] : string} ){
 ...
}
```

How can I modify the signature so that keyValue (array filled with strings) shall have an index of type string but after that I can use this still as an array (filled also with strings) in something like that (maybe this syntax is also wrong for using key AND value?):

```
keyValue.forEach(key, value => {
    //key is string
    //value is string
});
```

Comment: `string[] & { [s: string]: string};` should work but an array literal will not be assignable to it so it is of limited value. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the [Typescript index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) principle. When you're typing `keyValue : { [index:string] : string}` you're actually **not** defining an **array** at all. You're defining the default signature (~structure) of a Typescript object.

Thus the prototype you've written will accept any object with a string as a key, and a string as a value, eg:

```
{
  "keyOne": "valueOne",
  "keyTwo": "valueTwo"
}
```

In order to iterate over the pairs stored in your object, you can then:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(keyValue)) {
  /* Do something... */
}
```

I invite you to take a look at this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qnu3g7) I've created to illustrate it. Be careful that indicating an index signature such as the one you proposed **does not** ensure that the given object passed as argument will match (no error will be thrown at runtime).

Comment: Thank you, that does the job, only one thing left: If I want to declare an array with strings in it and with a string typed index, how would the syntax look like in typescript? - Thats not so easy to google as I thought because all I got was this object style approach found in my original post

Comment: I'm afraid that an **Array** can't do what you're asking for. According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array) _Each item in an array has a number attached to it, called a numeric index, that allows you to access it. In JavaScript, arrays start at index zero and can be manipulated with various methods._